# Hydrogen peroxide / sodium or potassium permanganate: reaction type

Tags: terminology, catalysis

I have some people on youtube stating the steam generating reaction of $$\ce{3H2O2 + 2KMnO4 → 3O2 + 2MnO2 + 2KOH + 2H2O}$$

is catalytic, from where I'm sitting it is purely stoichiometric. Can someone please enlighten me as to why some people would consider this reaction catalytic with the presence of the permanganate the catalyst?

If this reaction really is regarded as catalytic how is this so, it flies in the face of everything I've learnt about reaction types. I'm only an amateur, can someone who is proficient in their chemistry please clarify this.

Comment: Practically everything catalyzes the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide and manganese dioxide does an excellent job in that regard: just add some to hydrogen peroxide and watch it go. So decomposition of the potassium permanganate produces manganese dioxide and that does the job. Admittedly, this is not the simple case of adding a catalyst and having it neither be produced nor consumed in the reaction.

Comment: BTW, because the MnO2 is in the form of freshly generated nanoparticles, it is *particularly* active. Just adding powdered MnO2 to 3% peroxide evolves oxygen only slowly. Using 90% or stronger H2O2 produces a finely divided chemist.

Answer (score 2):

Learning from the comments and from looking at this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S6v-NMMnB4), there are two reactions:

$$\ce{3H2O2 +2KMnO4 -> 3O2 + 2MnO2 + 2K+ + 2OH- + 2H2O}\tag{1}$$

$$\ce{2H2O2 ->[MnO2] O2 + 2H2O}\tag{2}$$

The first reaction creates the catalyst $\ce{MnO2}$, the second generates oxygen gas even after the permanganate is used up. If you look closely at the video, you will see bubbles (oxygen) coming out of the solution even after the solution is colorless (i.e. permanganate has completely reacted).

For some more chemistry, I also recommend this video by Prof. Martyn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLUyeCC-2Ko

> Can someone please enlighten me as to why some people would consider this reaction catalytic with the presence of the permanganate the catalyst?

This is not accurate. What is true is that you need much less permanganate than hydrogen peroxide because only a little is required to make the catalyst, which then allows the reaction to proceed without being used up.