# How do I balance a hydrogen peroxide redox equation?

Tags: redox, oxidation-state

I have this equation:
$$\ce{H2O2 + MnO4- + H+ -> O2 + Mn^2+ + H2O}.$$
How do I balance it, since O has two different oxidation states on one side?

Comment: Check out Karsten’s answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/128423/79678.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You separate the reduction and oxidation half-equations, and then there is no issue with the oxidation state of oxygen on either side.

For the oxidation half-equation you start with (in acid solution)

$\ce{H2O2 -> O2}$

Clearly the hydrogen on the left is given off as $\ce{H^+(aq)}$ and the two oxygen atoms, being oxidized from -1 to 0 each, lose two electrons total. So the balanced oxidation half-reaction is

$\ce{H2O2 -> O2 + 2H^+ + 2 e^-}$

The reduction half-reaction should be no issue as it is just Mn(VII) being reduced to Mn(II). Then, as usual for redox reactions, identify multiples of the two half-reactions that balance the electrons, combine and cancel the balanced electrons to get your final result.